# Get UrlHelper from Controller. Asp.Net Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have a method that generates routes.
This method is called in the controller and I need to pass the 'UrlHelper' object.

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<string> GetNodes(UrlHelper urlHelper)
{
    string scheme = urlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme;
    List<string> nodes = new List<string>();
    //...
    return nodes;
}
```

Previously this was done as I see it this way:

`var result = _generator.GetNodes(this.Url);`

Now I'm getting an error.

`var result = _generator.GetNodes(this.Url);`

Answer (score 1):

Now it works, changed the type to interface:

```
GetSitemapNodes(IUrlHelper urlHelper)
```